# Script to search for 3 different users online and print that

Tags: grep

I am attempting to create a script where a user can enter 3 different arguments (usernames) to see if they are online.

I currently have `who | grep "^$1"` which will bring up whoever is searched then but when I try to add $2 and $3 like

```
who | grep "^$1" "^$2" "^$3"
```

it gives an error saying no such file or directory, but it works fine when I just have the single argument. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

`who | grep -e "^$1" -e "^$2" -e "^$3"` should do

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend doing something like this:

```
who | awk '{print $1}'
```

awk will print the first column or the names of the users currently logged on.

As terdon pointed out, to further narrow it down to three arguements:

`who | awk -v one=$1 -v two=$2 -v three=$3 '$1==one||$1==two||$1==three'`

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't help the OP look for three specific arguments. If you want to do it with `awk` use `who | awk  -v one="$1" -v two="$2" -v three="$3" '$1==one||$1==two||$1==three'`

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to experiment with effectively doing that with a for loop

Answer (score 1):

Grep behaves differently depending on the type of regular expression engine it is using. By default it uses [Basic Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html#bre) but can also use [Extended Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html#ere) with `-E` and, on `grep` versions that support this feature,  [Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/pcre.html) with `-P`.

BRE can only search for two patterns, no more. The syntax is:

```
grep 'pattern1\|pattern2'
```

ERE and PCRE can search for an arbitrary number, their syntax is the same in this respect, only the option flag changes:

```
grep -E 'pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|patternN'
grep -P 'pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|patternN'
```

So, for your case, you could do something like:

```
who | grep -E "^$1|^$2|^$3"
```